# A non-numeric value encountered PHP MYSQL opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in
>   /home/u914452720/domains/e-gilius.com/public_html/system/storagefnpzt1uybylm/modification/admin/model/catalog/manufacturer.php
>   on line 349Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in
>   /home/u914452720/domains/e-gilius.com/public_html/system/storagefnpzt1uybylm/modification/admin/model/catalog/manufacturer.php
>   on line 349

I get this error when I execute delete function:
admin/controller/catalog/manufacturer_download.php

```
function delete(){
        // var_dump("I AM IN DELETE");
        $this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');
        $postData = array();
        if(isset($_POST['submitdelete'])){
            //  var_dump("DELETE SUBMITTED");
            $entryID = $_POST['entryID'];// <-- gotta protect from sql injection.
            //  var_dump($entryID);
            $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->deleteManufacturersDownload($entryID);
        }
    }
```

If I var_dump($entryID) it gives result: string(1) "5"

admin/model/catalog/manufacturer.php

```
public function deleteManufacturersDownload($id){
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM ". DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_downloads WHERE id =" + "'"+$id+"'");
        return "success";
    }
```

Where I made mistake?

Comment: Try to change your `$id` to `(int)$id` in your query

Comment: Use parameterized queries instead of concatenating the values to the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up the string concatenation:

change

```
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM ". DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_downloads WHERE id =" + "'"+$id+"'");
```

to

```
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM ". DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_downloads WHERE id =" . "'" . $id . "'");
```

The error comes from trying to add string and numbers together:

```
echo "FOO" + 1337; // Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using + in query that is wrong  not need that use following code

```
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM ". DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_downloads WHERE id = '$id'");
```